# PDFLib get layer names and handles in PHP

Tags: java, php, layer, pdflib

im running PDFLib 9.x on a linux server with php 5.4. I need to get a list of all layers of a certain input PDF and then apply changes to some of them (visibility to be exact). Been digging through the API reference for quite some time now but can only find functions which create new layers in the output document and modify those. Also google doesnt supply anything valuable. I've found this example on their website but it's in Java and i lack the expertise to apply this code to PHP.

https://www.pdflib.com/pcos-cookbook/special/layers/

Maybe someone could help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to get a list of all layers of a certain input PDF and then apply changes to some of them (visibility to be exact).

this is not possible. When you import a PDF page with PDFlib+PDI, you can't change the content of the imported page. So it's not possible to change the layer properties.

The sample code you shared, is just for retrieving the layer information of an imported document, but not for manipulate them.

Comment: Thanks, i already thought so. Quite sad, i didn't think that manipulating layers is such a niche thing.

Comment: well, this might not be a niche topic. But in PDFlib it's simply depends to the technique how it works. All imported pages are like a "black box" and so there is no way to manipulate it.